# If we join multiple wires of different cross sectional area in series, then what will be same for the wires, tension or stress?

Tags: classical-mechanics, continuum-mechanics, stress-strain

If we join multiple wires of different cross sectional area in series, tie one end to the wall and pull the other, then what will be same for the wires, tension or stress?

Comment: first tie tow springs of different k together, what do you expect? than you can answer yourself.

Comment: Imagine one wire is a steel rod 100mm in diameter, and the other one is a human hair. Does that help you answer your own question?

Comment: thanks , got it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If they dont break, or stretch (ideal materials), then action = reaction. If you hang a ball, by a human hair, suspended from a steel.rod (3mm diam), then the tension in the rod is what supports the hair, and the tension in the hair is what pulls on the steel rod. Idealised, they are the same. Otherwise they'd start moving.

Same as in physics homework where the tension in a piece or string is the same at both ends, because its in equilibrium, and zero net force acting on any point.

So tension will be the same.  It doesnt depend on cross sectional area.